# File is not saving in the correct folder

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

i am using uploadify plugin in my asp.net page to upload my document.
now the problem is that i am using "AttachedFile" folder to take upload document and it is in the root directory of project and and my webpage where i am using plugin is within folder within folder,and all part is working well but the upload document is saving in the same folder where i have created my webpage
my jquery code is like this

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(
    function () {
        $("#<%=FileUpload1.ClientID %>").fileUpload({
            'uploader': '../../script/uploader.swf',
            'cancelImg': '../../images/cancel.png',
            'buttonText': 'Browse',
            'script': 'Upload.ashx',
            'folder': '~/AttachedFile/',
            'fileDesc': 'Image Files',
            'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png',
            'multi': true,
            'auto': false
        });
    }
    );
</script>
```

help me to overcome this problem
Thank You
:)

Comment: `~` can be used in ASP.Net context only. jQuery and uploadify do not understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use tilda in the `folder` path. You need to use `/` to reach the website root folder.

```
'folder': '/AttachedFile/',
```

Comment: yes i replace ~ with / "../../AttachedFile" but it not working yet again file is saving in the same folder where i created the webpage

Answer (score 0):

try

```
folder:'../AttachedFile/',
```